# How to disable automatic selection of frameworks in PCL projects?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013, portable-class-library

In a Portable Class Project in Visual Studio 2013, when I select

- .NET Framework 4 and higher
- Windows Store Apps (Windows 8) and higher
- Windows Phone 8

Visual Studio claims that **Silverlight 5** supports every available functionality that is portable between the other frameworks I selected and selects it automatically. But it's wrong because I need to use /unsafe compiler option which is not possible in Silverlight applications.

I select .NET Framework 4.5 instead of 4 as a workaround, so Visual Studio doesn't select Silverlight 5 automatically, but it shouldn't be needed since the project is perfectly compatible with .NET Framework 4 as well.

How can I get around that?
Is there anything I can change in the project file, like `ProjectTypeGuids`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you certainly *can* get around it.  It just takes a bit of surgery on the .csproj file for the PCL project.  Open it in a text editor, Notepad will do fine, and add this line to the `<PropertyGroup>`, after the ProjectTypeGuids property:

```
  <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
```

Which is enough to fool MSBuild and the compiler to allow you to use unsafe code.

I can't think of any failure scenario, you won't lose that property either when you make changes in the PCL project and rewrite the .csproj file.  Your only nemesis could be a hyper-active Store validator that will reject your app, I consider the odds very low since unsafe code is otherwise fine.  Just don't use it in a Silverlight project :)

Comment: Worked like charm for unsafe blocks, +1 and thank you. But it turned out selecting Silverlight has more restrictions than I thought. I can't use any API in the framework that uses pointers (`String` has only three constructors, for example) and there is no `StructLayout.Pack` property. I'll update the question.

Comment: That's where that ends, you cannot magically make missing declarations re-appear.  Surely you can work around this by copying.